# Find out how many different 'brands' (custom dim) a user looks at on average?

Tags: google-analytics

Our website has many related products from a large number of different brands

I'd like to try and use Google Analytics data to find out, on average, how many different brands - which I have set as a hit level custom dimension - a user will look at over a given time period

I'm not sure if this is possible, but it would be really cool to know!

Helps with understanding brand loyalty/defection

I started by creating a simple custom report to see how many manufacturers get seen by how many users, but I don't know where to go next with this question in order to answer it!

Comment: this question isn't really programing related you might have better luck on the Google Analytics community on google+ https://plus.google.com/u/0/communities/114481059214254340537